# merge javascript files in directory with node uglify + watch?

Tags: node.js, watch, dust.js, client-side-templating

### Goal:

*I am trying to build an effortless workflow for client side templating development.*

### Doc Root:

```
/views/uncompiled/
/static/js/compiled/
```

We start in `/views/uncompiled/`

This is where I can build stuff out, like `/views/uncompiled/index.html` for example.

Im building **[dust.js](http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/)** templates, so I am using **[dusterjs](https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs)** too listen for changes in my `/views/uncompiled/` directory, and automatically render compiled `*.js` counterparts in my `/static/js/compiled/` directory.

So `/views/uncompiled/index.html` renders out `/static/js/compiled/index.js` anytime a change is saved.

### Problem:

My `layout.html` is growing bigger. I need to include a new `*.js` script everytime I add another template:

```
<head>
    <script src='/static/js/compiled/index.js'></script>
    <script src='/static/js/compiled/header.js'></script>
    <script src='/static/js/compiled/footer.js'></script>
    <script src='/static/js/compiled/baconstrips.js'></script>
    ...
</head>
```

### Solution:

Use another watch on the `/static/js/compiled/` folder too automatically concat `*.js` into a single `app.js` that will always be included in my `<head>` anytime the contents of that folder changes:

```
<head>
    <script src='/static/js/app.js'></script>
</head>
```

### Question:

I would like to use a concatonation tool like **[Uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)** that also does compression.

- Are there any node packages that automate the solution above?
- Is there a native function of **[Uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)** that already does this?

Comment: Uglifyjs already does compression, and the readme shows how you can call it from Node. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: @mihai My "Question" block was a little malformmed I guess, but really what I'm looking for is a solution under the "Solution" block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/). It has the ability to watch/concentate/minify your files through various contributed modules. Takes a little getting used to (I still am myself) but you will end up with a custom build process that works the way that **you** want it to work, which is priceless.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have a great follow-up question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622116/grunt-js-watch-daemon