# Grunt.js Watch Forever

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, forever

### Goal:

I am trying to run a `watch` task in my `Gruntfile.js` as a daemon.

Normally, I would execute this script like: `grunt watch`.

### Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ''
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['static/js/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'app.js'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= concat.dist.src %>'],
      tasks: ['concat']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```

### Question:

**How do I spawn** `grunt watch` **as a daemon?**

### Update:

*It appears as though considerations for this have already been made:*
https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub#watching-forever
https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub/issues/3

Comment: Not sure why you would want to run grunt with forever. The point with forever is to keep a server alive? Would `nohup grunt watch &` work?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren Monitoring processes, starting/stopping with `forever` would be much more fluid than using `nohup`. I will need to be able to spawn muitiple grunt jobs for different projects, im currently looking into github.com/shama/grunt-hub which looks promising.

Comment: I've been doing something like this on a Vagrant VM, it makes for a nice pre-packaged workflow for teams with varied skill sets.

Answer (score 3):

you can use https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever exmaple

```
forever start gruntstart.js
```

gruntstart.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('grunt watch > log/grunt.log',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
           console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
});
```

Comment: that worked for me, however... what's the current path for exec?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie in javascript, but I solved this problem with: **tmux**

1. One pane for simple operations like git and etc.
2. Other is for "**grunt watch**"

Even if I close the console **tmux will go on** with watching :D
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4clqc.jpg