# Need to Perform a Grunt Watch Forever

Tags: gruntjs, daemon, watch

I'm new to Node.js and Grunt... I'm attempting to use Node.js and Grunt on a Windows server to watch my main.less file and do a standard compile and concatinate. I'm able to do this while the command prompt is open, but I need this to run as a daemon while not logged into the server since the .less files get deployed from our CMS that sits in the cloud.

I found promising documentation in Grunt-Forever, but it requires you to point to an application, while I just want to perform the grunt watch task.

Someone else asked a similar question 9 months ago, but nobody gave an answer:
[Grunt.js Watch Forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622116/grunt-js-watch-forever)

I tried this from the command line:

> FWIW, you can do forever /usr/local/bin/grunt --base . watch to use forever with grunt watch atm.

But, I got errors.

Here is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('watch', [ 'watch' ]);

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      js: {
        src: [
          'js/global.js','js/googlemap.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/main.min.js'
      },
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        mangle: false
      },
      js: {
        files: {
          'js/main.min.js': ['js/main.min.js']
        }
      }
    },
    less: {
      style: {
        files: {
          "css/style.css": "less/main.less"
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['js/global.js','js/googlemap.js'],
        tasks: ['concat:js', 'uglify:js']
      },
      css: {
        files: ['less/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:style']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

};
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to specify what are the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use node to call grunt, use PM2 to run and manage node.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `grunt watch` task with `nohup`. Since you mentioned "Windows server" you can check this answer about [nohup equivalent in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382082/whats-the-nohup-on-windows). Then you will have the grunt task running even when you log out of the server.